# How to increase the width/height of an image, with the origin staying centered

Tags: html, css

I have an image:

```
<img src="my_image.png"/>
```

And I want it to increase its width and height respectively, but origin should have from center. Because generally when the image size increases, the origin is in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think image origin means-some peoples said it pivot . It's like a gravity center. When we increase image width, while increasing the top - left corner of image remains constant and width increases towards right corner, same height increases towards bottom,

He want to increase height and width from center, not from RHS or bottom
I think final solution is to use JQuery

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can get your desired results through `display:table-cell;` `vertical-align:middle;` & `text-align:center`; see the below code :-

you can increase the width & height as per your requirement image will come in the center.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
      <img src="http://dummy-images.com/abstract/dummy-107x160-RedDots.jpg" />
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent {
    display:table-cell;
    width : 700px;
    height : 400px;
    background-color: black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

demo :- http://tinkerbin.com/IZxFN8cH

Comment: Guys did u tried fixed width for Parent element, coz in this jsfiddle, if Image size is bigger than parent, then parent height also increasing, which is should not be :)

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

[http://jsfiddle.net/4yR8M/](http://jsfiddle.net/4yR8M/1)

css:

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #123;    
}

#container img {
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="your/image/url"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use: transform:scale();

Example :transform:scale(1.1);